# Preventing buttons posting back

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, web, back

I have a set of controls which take inputs, some of them require validation.

However, a few controls at the bottom of this form, don't actually have anything to do with form itself but still do postback, which requires the form to be validated. This is a hinderence.

I want to be able to trigger a function to update the form view with out having to fill in any information yet.

Stuff like, if i want to add multiple products to a page from a dropdown list but do not want to cause the form to post back, how do I do that?

Comment: Then set `AutoPostback` to `false`.

Comment: you can also use `CausesValidation=fase` if you want a postback but don't want to validate inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options, but your question is not yet clear. What controls should not cause postbacks?

1. Most controls have a `AutoPostback` property which you can set to `false`(although this is default for the most)
2. Another option is to use HTML controls instead which don't post back to the server
3. You can also set `CausesValidation` to `false`
4. You could use [`ValidationGroups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx) to prevent validation for different controls

Comment: I'm trying to create Package, which contains a few products which the customer can choose. So I have a DropDownList which has all the products in them, and everytime a customer selects a product it gets added to a panel, they can select multiple products!

Answer (score 0):

u can simply use HTML contols like this one

```
<input type="Button">value</input>
```

this wont post back

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax library control to prevents auto post back. In ajax library there is one control **Update panel you put your some controls only which require post back and other which have not you put out side update panel...